# How to connect UILabel to other class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel

I have a UI label on a viewcontroller and a string(**accuracy**) that's on a nsobject. I want to put the string on the uilabel that constantly updates because when  u print the string(**accuracy**) it updates. Can someone help me ? Thanks

```
class Home: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var lbl_accuracy: UILabel! 
}
```

---

```
class PBLocation: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {

            switch(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()) {

            case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
                print("No access")

            case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:

                let accuracy = String(format: "%.4f", (locations.last?.horizontalAccuracy)!)
                print("accuracy = \(accuracy)")
            }
        } else {
            print("Location services are not enabled")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use your viewController as CLLocationManagerDelegate then you can directly change the value `self.lbl_accuracy.text = accuracy` in the line where you are currently printing `print("accuracy = \(accuracy)")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [delegate design pattern](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/design-patterns-delegation--cms-23901) to send location accuracy to Home VC. First create `LocationUpdatable protocol` and add `updateLocationAccuracy(_ accuracy: String) function`. Create a weak delegate object in PBLocation class and now you can send accuracy object to Home VC via updateLocationAccuracy method. Finally Confirm to the LocationUpdatable protocol in Home VC and implement `updateLocationAccuracy(_ accuracy: String)` function and most important set the Home VC the delegate of `LocationUpdatable` delegate object.

```
protocol LocationUpdatable: class {
    func updateLocationAccuracy(_ accuracy: String)
}

//Confirm to the LocationUpdatable
class Home: UIViewController, LocationUpdatable {

    @IBOutlet weak var lbl_accuracy: UILabel!

    let location = PBLocation()
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = location
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        location.delegate = self
    }

    func updateLocationAccuracy(_ accuracy: String) {
        lbl_accuracy.text = accuracy
    }
}

//Create a delegate object
class PBLocation: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    weak var delegate: LocationUpdatable?

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {

            switch(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()) {

            case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
                print("No access")

            case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:

                let accuracy = String(format: "%.4f", (locations.last?.horizontalAccuracy)!)
                print("accuracy = \(accuracy)")
                if let delegate = delegate {
                    delegate.updateLocationAccuracy(accuracy)
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Location services are not enabled")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Introduction to Key-Value Observing Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177i)

[Key-Value Observing](http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/)

1. NSNotification & NSNotificationCenter
2. Key-Value Observing
3. Delegates
4. Callbacks

---

NSNotification & NSNotificationCenter

```
// new here
let accuracyNoti = NSNotification.Name(rawValue:"accuracyNoti") 
// end

class PBLocation: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        switch(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()) {
            case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
                print("No access")
            case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
                let accuracy = String(format: "%.4f", (locations.last?.horizontalAccuracy)!)
                print("accuracy = \(accuracy)")

                // new here
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: accuracyNoti, object: nil, userInfo: ["accuracy": accuracy)  
                // end
            }
        } else {
            print("Location services are not enabled")
        }
    }
}


class Home: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var lbl_accuracy: UILabel! 

    // new here
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(didMsgRecv(notification:)),  
                                           name: accuracyNoti, object: nil) 
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    func didMsgRecv(notification:NSNotification) {
         let userInfo = notification.userInfo as! [String: AnyObject]
         let accuracy = userInfo["accuracy"] as! String 
         lbl_accuracy.text = accuracy      
    } 
    // end
}
```